# how can i store fibonacci sequence in a matrix

Tags: c, matrix, fibonacci

well, i need to store the fibonacci sequence in a 2x5 matrix but what im doing its not working. here's my attempt

```
int main()
{
    int i,j,k;
    int mat[2][5];
    mat[0][0]=0;
    mat[0][1]=1;
    k=2;
    for (i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<5; j++)
        {
            
            mat[i][k]=mat[i][j]+mat[i][j+1];
           
            k++;
        }
    }
    for(i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<5; j++)
        {
            printf("%d\t",mat[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If the assignment is to teach you that a 2x5 is stored in the same 10 consecutive integers as a 1x10, then you can make the job a whole lot easier. Store them as a 1x10, cast it as a 2x5, and then iterate over the 2x5 to do the printing.

Comment: `mat[i][j+1]` will exceed the array limits on the final iteration.

Comment: ... and `mat[i][k]` will too, on the final *five* iterations, because of the initialisation `k=2;` and because `i` can be `1`. This is likely to **break** something. "Not working" isn't a helpful problem description though.

Comment: thank you @JeffHolt , i managed to solve the problem with your tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using the row and column of the matrix to calculate the "position" of that element at the fibonacci sequence?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#define ROWS 2
#define COLS 5

int fibonacci(int position)
{
    if (position == 0)
        return 0;

    if (position == 1)
        return 1;

    return fibonacci(position - 1) + fibonacci(position - 2);
}

int main()
{
    int mat[ROWS][COLS];

    for(int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++)
    {
        for(int col = 0; col < COLS; col++)
        {
            /*
            [0,0] = 0 [0,1] = 1, [0,2] = 2, [0,3] = 3, [0,4] = 4
            [1,0] = 5 [1,1] = 6, [1,2] = 7, [1,3] = 8, [1,4] = 9
            */
            mat[row][col] = fibonacci(COLS * row  + col);

            printf("%3d, ", mat[row][col]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please, notice that this solution calculates the fibonacci value every time from the start. Since your problem seemed to be storing at the matrix, the main part of the solution that you are looking for is the "position" itself and as such, this was the focus for this answer. In case my assumption was wrong, feel free to modify it in order to avoid calculating each element of the sequence from start every time.

Comment: could you explain to me why it didn't show three times the number 1? like, when col = 0 it'll return 1 for the 0,0 position, the same goes for col = 1, and then when col = 2 its supposed to return 1 as well right?

Comment: @Thorsen, you are correct, my answer was mistaken for the 0th position, fixed! It should be `if (position == 0) return 0;` from the start. Now it is displayed correctly as `0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, [...]`

Answer (score 0):

Would you please try the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i, j, k;
    int mat[2][5] = {{0, 1}};

    for (k = 2; k < 10; k++) {
        mat[k / 5][k % 5] = mat[(k - 1) / 5][(k - 1) % 5] + mat[(k - 2) / 5][(k - 2) % 5];
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            printf("%d\t", mat[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```